# tipc protocol in windows

Tags: windows, linux, networking, tipc

Any idea for [TIPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_Inter-process_Communication) protocol on Windows systems or any similar protocol which is available on windows ?

Thanks
Arpit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia basically says it's general-purpose communication library.

If you're designing an HPC cluster, take a look at "Microsoft High Performance Computing" in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496121.aspx bot keep in mind that API only exists on some editions of their server OSes.

I think you'll only get better answer when you'll describe what kind of tasks are you going to accomplish.

P.S. I don't actually get the point of TIPC, even after reading the programmer's guide.
It seems using the API is not easier then using sockets.
But when you're using sockets, at least you've got tons of good books, online manuals, and easy to use debugging and diagnostic tools.

Comment: TIPC works best in the cluster mode. It detects the network topology.So the communication is more optimized in the cluster environment 
My purpose is to get the similar thing in Windows. Porting TIPC in windows is one option but that will take lot of time and understanding.